# Saving a Python Terminal command as something easy to remember

Tags: python, terminal, command

I want to run a Python file easily via my terminal with a new command.
(I am using Windows 10)
Is there a terminal command like

`python "script.py" --save newname`

that would let me run script.py by just typing the command "newname"?

I have tried running `python "script.py" --newcommand newname` , but to no avail. If anybody could provide me with a command similar to this that would allow me to achieve what I need.

Thank you.

Comment: Create a shell alias that does it.

Comment: `alias newname='python /path/to/script.py'`

Comment: This is hardly specific to python. It's how you create a shortcut for any command.

Comment: Which operating system? The problem with shell aliases or shell command is that they are operating system specific. You may be abte to just run `script.py` or `./script.py` or even just `script` depending on how things are setup.

Comment: @Barmar I tried using the alias method, and got this error:
`alias : This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'fib=python printfib.py' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ alias fib='python printfib.py'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (fib=python printfib.py:String) [Get-Alias], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAliasCommand`

Comment: @tdelaney I am running Python 3.12 coded in Visual Studio Code on the Windows 10 operating system

Comment: Does running `printfib.py` or perhaps `printfib` work? If the .py file type has been setup, windows should know that its a python executable.

Comment: @tdelaney 

`PS C:\Users\1005447> printfib
printfib : The term 'printfib' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ printfib
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (printfib:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: That's a command for a Linux shell. I don't know what the equivalent is in PowerShell.

Comment: The question should say what OS you're using, since this is OS-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias) command in Windows PowerShell:

```
function test {python script.py}
Set-Alias -Name newname -Value test
```

Afterwards, the command can be invoked as `newname`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following to the first line of your Python code

#!/bin/python3

2. run chmod

chmod 755 script.py

3. run python

./script.py

Comment: They're apparently using Windows, not Linux, so this won't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).